# Reactjs. I can not run the demo locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I downloaded the library: https://github.com/jquense/react-widgets

I opened file: docs/index.html

Console shows an error:

> GET file:///F:/Extjs/breeze/react-widgets-2.6.1/docs/docs.js
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I changed this line:

Before:

```
 <script src="docs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After:

```
<script src="components/docs.jsx" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Console shows an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {      docs.jsx:3

How do I run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/jquense/react-widgets
cd react-widgets
npm install 
gulp dev-docs
```

then in my browser http://localhost:8080/docs/index.htm#/

did that work for you?

cheers
oliver

Comment: You should get a screen shot or make it on some public server, as `localhost` means `myIP`, so whoever go to that links will only get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` or something like `page not found` unless they also have run a server that listen to port:8080, and they have route rule to accept `docs/index.htm#/`.